# Is it possible to not show xmlelement when null in plsql?

Tags: xml, plsql

I have a question regarding xmlelement in plsql.

My code looks like:

```
SELECT XMLROOT(
  XMLELEMENT("FirstElement", 'data1'),
  (SELECT XMLAGG(
    XMLELEMENT( "IterationElement1",
      XMLFOREST(
        'value1' AS "FirstSubElement"
        'value2' AS "SecondSubElement"
      )
    ),
    XMLELEMENT( "IterationElement2", CASE WHEN a <> c THEN DECODE( a, 1, 'Y', 'N') ELSE NULL END),
    XMLELEMENT( "IterationElement3", CASE WHEN b <> c THEN DECODE( b, 1, 'Y', 'N' ) ELSE NULL END)
  )
  FROM T2 where id = in_id
  )
)
FROM T1
WHERE id = in_id
```

Currently for IterationElement2 and 3 i would like for them to not show in the output when the value is null, is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

Show xmlelement only if it has a value

```
CASE WHEN a <> c THEN XMLELEMENT("IterationElement2",DECODE( a, 1, 'Y', 'N')) else null END
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, not sure why i did not think of moving the case statement outside the element